# In Selenium, does ClickAndHold work with webdriver and chrome?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to make a click-and-drag event work using Selenium Webdriver (2.15). It works fine when using FF, but in Chrome it does not. In Chrome, it appears to have no effect. Here's what my code looks like:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(GuiOps.driver);
builder.MoveToElement(fromElem).ClickAndHold().MoveToElement(toElem).Release().Build().Perform();
```

Has anyone gotten ClickAndHold() to work successfully using Chrome?

Answer (score 6):

Turns out this is a known issue. There's a workaround posted at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92312 . Basically, you add a MoveByOffset(1,1) immediately after that ClickAndHold() call and it works.

Comment: We have been looking for this post for hours, can you mark this answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: I wouldn't mark it as accepted, it didn't work for me or the person who commented on the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 1):

First post/comment here. :)
Well, it worked for me. All you need to give is a bit of a pause after the "moveByOffset(1, 1)". It seems that the script is executing faster than it should. Here's a piece of code that worked for me:
"actions.clickAndHold(we).moveByOffset(1, 1).pause(1000).perform();". Hope it helps.